# In a group, what is the definition of $g^{-n}$?

Tags: group-theory

Sorry for the short question, I would just like to check something. My book asks to prove $(g^{n})^{-1}=g^{-n}$, but $g^{-n}$ is never defined. My guess is that the definition of $g^{-n}$ is $(g^{-1})^{n}$. Am I correct?

Comment: I presume $n$ is a positive integer? You could define it as $(g^n)^{-1}$ or you could define it as $(g^{-1})^n$. Take your pick.

Comment: You may be correct. In any case what should be proved is that $(g^n)^{-1} = (g^{-1})^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you're correct $g^{-n}$ usually denotes $$\underbrace{g^{-1}\cdots g^{-1}}_{n \text{ times}}.$$

Comment: also denotes $$\left(\underbrace{g\, \cdots \, g}_{n \text{ times}}\right)^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

I have a small problem with what he wants you to show, because by the sounds of it he's asking you to prove a definition...

Anyhow from deducing from the definitions you know already we can at least show that *defining* $g^{-n}\equiv(g^{n})^{-1}$ holds no ambiguity. Now we know, by definition, that:
$$g^n=\underbrace{g \cdots g}_{n \text{ times}}$$
and also that
$$(abc)^{-1}= c^{-1} b^{-1} a^{-1}$$
that is, the inverse of a product is the product of the inverses "backwards".

Using this, we see:

$\begin{array}
\ (g^n)^{-1} &= (\underbrace{g \cdots g}_{n \text{ times}})^{-1} \\
&= \underbrace{g^{-1} \cdots g^{-1}}_{n \text{ times}} \\
&= (g^{-1})^n
\end{array}$

and since $(g^n)^{-1}=(g^{-1})^n$, there's no ambiguity in the definition, so we can just confidently say
$$g^{-n}\equiv(g^{n})^{-1} = (g^{-1})^n.$$